# How do I get a usable email message reference id from headers to use in a Microsoft Graph query?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to use the references message ID in email headers of a forwarded email in Office 365 to then find the original email that has that message ID.

The references ID in the forwarded email's headers would show something like what's shown below. Note I'm obtaining these headers from Microsoft Graph by adding `&$select=internetMessageHeaders` to my query using sender/subject to find the forwarded email.

```
{
  "name": "References",
  "value": "<CAOLK2SAEzvs=-6Rs5cTbgORNivQVK2AvMJDJT8o+ghx-XhCn7w@mail.gmail.com>"
}
```

However, if I take this and use it in a query like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<CAOLK2SAEzvs=-6Rs5cTbgORNivQVK2AvMJDJT8o+ghx-XhCn7w@mail.gmail.com>'`

I do not receive any results.

If I hunt down the original email in Microsoft Graph using sender and subject, I see the following for the `internetMessageId` field for the original email:

```
{
  "name": "Message-ID",
  "value": "<CAOLK2SC6s9Me05kYRqeuEHKK8DrQbXx34ScT0AzGOFFLMdRapg@mail.gmail.com>"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what Office 365 or Microsoft Graph is doing to change `CAOLK2SAEzvs=-6Rs5cTbgORNivQVK2AvMJDJT8o+ghx-XhCn7w` into `CAOLK2SC6s9Me05kYRqeuEHKK8DrQbXx34ScT0AzGOFFLMdRapg`? It looks like some sort of encoding, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Ultimately I would like to be able to transform what I'm getting in the references ID header such that I can turn around and use that ID to find the original email using Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the issue. In my test message-ID I have the characters = and +

These characters must be URL encoded to %3D and %2B before being used in the $filter query. When they are URL encoded, I am able to find the original email using MS Graph.

Answer (score 3):

The `id` is a hashed value that, among other things, includes the path/folder that the message resides in. So if you, for example, move a message (say from Inbox to Archive) then you should expect the `id` to change.

For tracking a message, regardless of its location, you should use the `internetMessageId` (`$select=internetMessageId`) property instead.

Comment: Right, so I'm not using the ID property from Graph. This references ID/message ID is from the headers of the emails' themselves and should not change when the email changes location in a user's mailbox. I'm extracting the references message ID from headers which should be the internetMessageId for the original email, but Graph displays something besides what's actually in the headers as the message ID/internetMessageId in that it's been encoded or altered in some way (see my example in the question).

Comment: If I open the forwarded and original email in Outlook and view headers there, I am shown the <CAOLK2SAEzvs=-6Rs5cTbgORNivQVK2AvMJDJT8o+ghx-XhCn7w@mail.gmail.com> value, which makes sense. They share that common data point. But when I go to Graph that ID doesn't work, it has some how modified it and expects for you to use that modified version if you're doing $filter=internetMessageId eq <msgId>

Comment: Any other ideas Marc? You're my best connection to the Microsoft Graph space right now. I did try another test where a coworker sent me a message from their Office 365 account in our tenant, then I forwarded it to another mailbox, and the references message ID and message ID (internetMessageID in Graph) stayed the same and my use-case worked perfectly. Maybe Graph only does this to internet message IDs for outside senders? I'm fine with the modification its doing, I just need to understand how I can reproduce what it's doing so I can find messages with the message ID from the references header

Comment: Graph isn't actually generating those ID's, it's entirely controlled by Exchange. You should get the same ID back from the EWS, Graph and Outlook REST APIs. Keep in mind that `Message-ID` is defined in RFC2822 as unique to each _instance_ of a message. So if you send an email to two mailboxes, each instance (your sent item, both received emails) will have different IDs.

Comment: `You should get the same ID back from the EWS, Graph and Outlook REST APIs`

You're right I should, what I'm saying is I am not getting the same value back from Graph as the others when the message is originating from some external senders (like Gmail).

Comment: can you please go to the Azure Portal and submit an issue if this is the case? here's how to submit it https://twitter.com/jthake/status/1030489336439959553

Answer (score 0):

You need to request PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES, PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES_A, PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES_W MAPI property (0x1039)

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x1039')
```

The doc for 0x1039 located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaginternetreferences-canonical-property).

For the Message id, from what i can tell from the [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) internetMessageId is the property that is already there that you are looking for.

The doc for singleValueExtendedProperties is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft Graph v1.0 and beta, you can obtain "immutable ids" by sending an additional HTTP header in your API requests:

`Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"`

I've put immutable in italics as this is the term Microsoft uses. Be aware of the following caveats, the ID will change if:

- The user moves the item to an archive mailbox;
- The user exports the item (to a PST, as an MSG file, etc.) and re-imports it into their mailbox;
- The user creates a draft which they later send;

You can also convert existing ids to immutable ones by the following request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/translateExchangeIds
{ 
  "inputIds" : 
  [ 
    "AQMkAGM2…" 
  ], 
  "targetIdType" : "restImmutableEntryId", 
  "sourceIdType" : "restId" 
}
```

Which will give you the response:

```
HTTP 200 OK

{ 
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.convertIdResult)", 
  "value": [ 
    { 
      "targetId": "AAkALgAA...", 
      "sourceId": "AQMkAGM2..."
    } 
  ] 
}
```